# Stop click action on this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a simple FAQ's accordion using jQuery and i'm trying to disable the extra click on `this` because when `this` is clicked it will just slide up again as it's the one being clicked again.

How can I disable the click or disable the action where it slides back up and down again once the button (the one being clicked) has been clicked?

```js
(function($) {
  $('.c-accordion__panel').hide();
  $('.c-accordion__heading').click(function() {
    $('.c-accordion__panel').slideUp('fast'); //slide up panel
    $(this).parent('div').children('.c-accordion__panel').slideDown('fast'); //slide down panel
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="faqs" class="clearfix pb3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3 class="pb3">Colocation FAQ</h3>
    <div class="c-accordion">
      <div class="c-accordion__heading flex justify-between border">
        <h4>heading 1</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="c-accordion__panel active">
        <p>this one has active Mumblecore biodiesel semiotics vice, sustainable banh mi ennui irony vape waistcoat drinking vinegar banjo scenester put a bird on it kickstarter. Dreamcatcher forage tousled gluten-free, taiyaki 3 wolf moon truffaut. Next
          level vinyl kinfolk, beard fanny pack biodiesel pinterest cold-pressed tumeric venmo franzen affogato disrupt wolf 90's. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-accordion">
      <div class="c-accordion__heading flex justify-between border">
        <h4>heading2</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="c-accordion__panel">
        <p>Mumblecore biodiesel semiotics vice, sustainable banh mi ennui irony vape waistcoat drinking vinegar banjo scenester put a bird on it kickstarter. Dreamcatcher forage tousled gluten-free, taiyaki 3 wolf moon truffaut. Next level vinyl kinfolk,
          beard fanny pack biodiesel pinterest cold-pressed tumeric venmo franzen affogato disrupt wolf 90's. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-accordion">
      <div class="c-accordion__heading flex justify-between border">
        <h4>heading3</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="c-accordion__panel">
        <p>Mumblecore biodiesel semiotics vice, sustainable banh mi ennui irony vape waistcoat drinking vinegar banjo scenester put a bird on it kickstarter. Dreamcatcher forage tousled gluten-free, taiyaki 3 wolf moon truffaut. Next level vinyl kinfolk,
          beard fanny pack biodiesel pinterest cold-pressed tumeric venmo franzen affogato disrupt wolf 90's. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clicked element is `.c-accordion__heading`, and the element you want to call `slideUp` on is `.c-accordion__panel`, which is the next sibling. So 
 you can add `.not($(this).next())` before calling `slideUp`:

```js
(function($) {
  $('.c-accordion__panel').hide();
  $('.c-accordion__heading').click(function() {
    $('.c-accordion__panel').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast'); //slide up panel
    $(this).parent('div').children('.c-accordion__panel').slideDown('fast'); //slide down panel
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="faqs" class="clearfix pb3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3 class="pb3">Colocation FAQ</h3>
    <div class="c-accordion">
      <div class="c-accordion__heading flex justify-between border">
        <h4>heading 1</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="c-accordion__panel active">
        <p>this one has active Mumblecore biodiesel semiotics vice, sustainable banh mi ennui irony vape waistcoat drinking vinegar banjo scenester put a bird on it kickstarter. Dreamcatcher forage tousled gluten-free, taiyaki 3 wolf moon truffaut. Next
          level vinyl kinfolk, beard fanny pack biodiesel pinterest cold-pressed tumeric venmo franzen affogato disrupt wolf 90's. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-accordion">
      <div class="c-accordion__heading flex justify-between border">
        <h4>heading2</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="c-accordion__panel">
        <p>Mumblecore biodiesel semiotics vice, sustainable banh mi ennui irony vape waistcoat drinking vinegar banjo scenester put a bird on it kickstarter. Dreamcatcher forage tousled gluten-free, taiyaki 3 wolf moon truffaut. Next level vinyl kinfolk,
          beard fanny pack biodiesel pinterest cold-pressed tumeric venmo franzen affogato disrupt wolf 90's. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-accordion">
      <div class="c-accordion__heading flex justify-between border">
        <h4>heading3</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="c-accordion__panel">
        <p>Mumblecore biodiesel semiotics vice, sustainable banh mi ennui irony vape waistcoat drinking vinegar banjo scenester put a bird on it kickstarter. Dreamcatcher forage tousled gluten-free, taiyaki 3 wolf moon truffaut. Next level vinyl kinfolk,
          beard fanny pack biodiesel pinterest cold-pressed tumeric venmo franzen affogato disrupt wolf 90's. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your javascript to this

```
(function ($) {
        $('.c-accordion__panel').hide();
        $('.c-accordion__heading').click(function(){
            $('.c-accordion__panel').slideUp('fast'); //slide up panel
            if($(this).parent('div').children('.c-accordion__panel').is(':hidden')){
               $(this).parent('div').children('.c-accordion__panel').slideDown('fast'); //slide down panel
            }

        });
    })(jQuery);
```